# Importing/Adding/Combine to a .blend file from a .blend file

Tags: import, blender, render-to-texture, fbx, wavefront

I have 2 .blend files. I want to combine the information of both files. Is there a way to import .blend files. Into another .blend file.

Why would I do that?
I am having trouble if I import the model to another type of file.

When I did it in fbx the model was pure black. (And fbx binary only "worked")
Obj was a bit better, though it added transparency, and I did not need that.
Anything else, failed to import the armature properly, or made the textures even worse than fbx and obj.

Inshort. I want to preserve the file's information.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you referring to `Shift + F1` and then going to Object and selecting the object?

Answer (score 1):

You can import items from another blend file without exporting to other file formats. There are two methods that offer different benefits.

1. `File->Append`. This will copy the selected item/s into the current blend file.
2. `File->Link`. This will allow you to use the external item/s in the current blend file, this is referred to as a [linked library](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html). This differs from append in that the item data stays in the external file while it is visible in the current file. Note that editing of the item can only be done in it's original file which will then be visible in the blend file it was linked into. To animate an item, a [proxy](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/linked_libraries.html#proxy-objects) is made to allow limited editing of the external object.

In both cases when a blend file is selected in the file browser, you will get to choose different items within the blend file. This allows you to choose individual objects, materials, groups...

[image: example append]

Note that importing an object will also import dependencies, such as the armature used in the armature modifier that the object has as well as the material it uses.